# android box stuck at boot logo

Tags: boot, boot-loop, unbricking

I have an android box which is a no name chinese one RK3066 cortex A9 8GB android 4.1. it's been stuck on boot logo and since there is no reset or power or volume button on it I couldn't get it to recovery mode.

however when I opened the device, I could see two holes which said recovery. when I used a pin to connect those two I got into recovery mode

the device goes to recovery mode but the only thing I see is an android guy resting and no option.I checked evey where and they all suggest to press power button to go to menus but my device has no button on it.

I used a same device and using Online Nandroid Backup I made a backup of the ROM and put it in a 16GB SD card root. the files are boot.img kernel.img recovery.img recoverlog.log. I put all these files on the SD card hoping that once into recovery mode the recovery automatically starts. maybe it should be packed or something, I don't know what is the format of a ROM file. it seems that it should be a zip file

I found another set of holes which are three and underneath is said DEBUG. I assume it's same as debug mode which normal android phone or tablets connect to the PC using micro usb cable which comes with them and since my device doesn't have micro USB I suppose this is the way of connecting to PC so perhaps through RK Batch tool something can be done but I don't know how it works.

I bought a male to male USB cable and cut one side which found three cables. Black, White and Green. but I don't know what is the sequence and I tried everything possible solution

I appreciate if anyone could help me with this[image]